# Can Community Guest users delete the owned file?

Tags: files, guest-user

Much appreciate if anyone can help me with the below.
I have a community where guest users update some information and upload files with a flow.

In the flow, users can delete files they uploaded once for any reason which works perfectly for SFDC logged in users but not for guest users.
The error message is:

> The flow tried to delete these records: null. This error occurred: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY: insufficient access rights on object id.

The object is `ContentDocument`.
Is there any way to allow guest users to delete files they own?

Thanks for your time and help!

Akiko